# Open access P Band Radar data

Tags: geospatial, aerial-photography

Are there any sources for open access P Band radar data? I need it for a single city block in the Middle East, outside United States.

The [Russian Aist 2D](https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=39133) has a P Band SAR on board, but the data seems to be not free, therefore not open data.

Answer (score 1):

NASA's [Remote Sensors](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/learn/remote-sensors) definitely has P Band data; filter the table in the link for "P Band".

Comment: Thanks. But it seems it is inside the US only. I need the data in middle east.

Comment: that's a pretty important detail; you should put that in your question.

Comment: done, added this info